# unnecessary guard on CakePHP deleteall

Tags: database, cakephp, sql-delete

I've taken over a CakePHP 2.9 code-base and am puzzled by code of the form:

```
$chkFeed = $this->UserFeed->find('count', array('conditions' => array('UserFeed.user_id' => $userID)));
if ($chkFeed > 0) {
    $this->UserFeed->deleteAll(array('UserFeed.user_id' => $userID));
}
```

surely that `if ...` guard is unnecessary?  You can just call `deleteAll` even if in fact no rows are deleted, right?  [This](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/models/deleting-data.html) says so, so why have the guard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"If" guard is unnecessary here .

Following code will also do your job perfectly . As deleteAll() works both way 
 match or not match. In both cases it will return  **true**.

```
$chkFeed = $this->UserFeed->find('count', array('conditions' => array('UserFeed.user_id' => $userID)));
$this->UserFeed->deleteAll(array('UserFeed.user_id' => $userID));
```

Comment: Yes, this will also do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks;  `$chkFeed` is only used in my code as the predicate of the `if` statement, so if the `if` is removed, so can the evaluation of `$chkFeed`.  Four lines down to one is worth having IMO.  Also, as a side-note, the code in my original posting was copied about ten times for ten separate tables;  in one case, the tested table (the `$this->X->find`) was different from the deleteAll table (the `$this->X->deleteAll`), which fact was concealed by the mass copy-paste mess.

Answer (score 0):

The *if* check  would be unnecessary if *deleteAll* only checks for the *userID* in a single table only.

However, deleteAll by default would run through the associated tables creating a join query every time this line is executed.

This won't matter much to most though, except you're performance intransigent and would see to fully optimizing all code.